# LoadError while running rails active_storage:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am new to ruby on rails and am trying to build a basic todo-list app. My ruby version is `2.5.5` and Rails version is `5.1.7`. I am trying to setup `active_storage` in my application but am unable to run the command `rails active_storage:install`. I am on a Windows 8.1 x64 system.

This is the error trace:

```
C:\Users\Sreekar\Documents\GitHub\todo-app>rails active_storage:install --trace
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_storage/engine
C:/Users/Sreekar/Documents/GitHub/todo-app/config/application.rb:4:in `require'
C:/Users/Sreekar/Documents/GitHub/todo-app/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/Sreekar/Documents/GitHub/todo-app/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
C:/Users/Sreekar/Documents/GitHub/todo-app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `block in perform'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have already tried to include `require active_storage/engine` in my `config/application.rb` file but it isn't working.

These are the contents of my `application.rb` file:

```
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'
require 'active_storage/engine'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module TodoApp
class Application < Rails::Application
config.load_defaults 5.1
```

I need to create 2 tables in my schema: `active_storage_blobs` and `active_storage_attachments` upon running `rails db:migrate`.
Would appreciate any help regarding how to get this to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active storage is supported and comes in default from Rails versions >= `5.2`. Your Rails version is `5.1.7`.

So, you should consider upgrading your app to Rails `5.2`([See this link](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-1-to-rails-5-2)) to use Active storage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @allenbrkn. I am now using rvm as version manager, and have updated my system to rails -v 6.0.0.rc1. The issue is I'm still unable to run a server, this time due to another LoadError --  cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not update to Rails 6.0 since it is now in stable state? Also, Rails 6.0 requires Ruby > `2.5.0`. Also, since you've upgraded from Rails 5.1 to 6.0, You'll need to follow these steps - https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-2-to-rails-6-0

Comment: Or maybe you'll first have to see the steps to convert Rails `5.1` to `5.2` from here - https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-1-to-rails-5-2 and then Upgrade from `5.2` to `6.0` from here - https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-2-to-rails-6-0. Just see the steps and I think it should solve all problems